# FileNotFoundExeption cuando salvo la salida de un programa en PowerShell y cmd

Tags: c, csv, vscode, cmd, powershell

tengo un problema y es que cuando quiero "guardarlo" como `.csv` me aparece que no lo encuentra o algo asi.

Aquí intento usando powershell primero guardando el archivo como `tiro.exe` para luego ejecutarlo (el cual si funciona) y para luego tratar de "guardarlo" como `.csv`, utilizo "guardar" porque no estoy seguro del como se dice.

[image]

Revisé que no fuera algún problema de escritura o algo similar pero no, me permite compilar el archivo y ejecutarlo normalmente pero como dije anteriormente al quererlo guardar como `.csv` no me es posible Mi problema es de urgencia debido a que tengo proyectos y examenes que hacer para la semana que entra y no eh pudo resolverlo traté cambiando de powershell a cmd (consejo que me dio mi profesor) pero ni asi me funciona, cuando quiero guardarlo en cmd me aparece "el sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado."

Y aqui fue usando cmd

[image]

En esta imagen se pueden ver 3 columnas con nueros enlistados, ese es el programa funcionando y no me muestra ningun error a correrlo

es decir, primero compilo el programa con `gcc tiroparab.c -o tiro -lm` y luego ejecuto el `tiro.exe` a lo cual en ambos casos todo va bien...ya cuando trato de pasar todos los datos a `.csv` ahi es cuando el erro empieza a fallar

A pesar de que ya revise que no se moviera de carpeta o el archivo se corrompiera y todo sigue normal

Revisando nuevamente, un compañero me sugirió que tratara de guardar el archivo como `.txt` para ver si me podia mostrar el texto y resulta que tampoco me permite hacer eso, lo cual es bastante raro porque anteriormente he guardado archivos `.txt` y todo funcionaba correctamente

No se si es mi pc o le falta algo más

Para ejecutar el archivo solo coloco `.\tiro.exe` y doy **enter**

[image]

justo como aparece en la parte inferor de color amarillo, asi es como hago que el programa inicie y los numeros de arriba del `.\tiro.exe` es el propio programa

como puedo solucionar este problema?

el codigo que trato de guardar es este

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double afx(double);
double afy(double);
double Vfx(double, double);
double Vfy(double, double);
double xf(double, double, double);
double yf(double, double, double);

int main(void){
    double x=0, y=0, Vx=10, Vy=10, t=0, dt=0.001, ax, ay;
    printf("t\tx\ty\n");
    do{
        printf("%lf\t%lf\t%lf\n", t, x, y);
        x=xf(x, dt, Vx);
        y=yf(y, dt, Vy);
        Vx=Vfx(Vx, dt);
        Vy=Vfy(Vy, dt);
        ax= -Vx*0.005;
        ay=-9.81-Vy*0.005;

        t += dt;

    }while(y>0);
}
double afx(double Vx){
    return 0;
}
double afy(double Vy){
    return -9.81;
}
double Vfx(double Vx, double dt){
    return Vx + dt*afx(Vx);
}
double Vfy(double Vy, double dt){
    return Vy + dt*afy(Vy);
}
double xf(double x , double dt, double Vx){
    return x+dt*Vx;
}
double yf(double y, double dt, double Vy){
    return y+dt*Vy;
}
```

y este es el error que me aparece cuando lo quiero guardar

out-file : Could not find file 'C:\Users\casham\Documents\Programacion\tiro.csv'.
At line:1 char:1

- .\tiro.exe > tiro.csv
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
  ```

Comment: No entiendo. Quieres guardar un archivo de C como un archivo csv? Eso parece un asunto de tu editor de código. Busca la opción de "guardar como". Es ese tu problema?

Comment: Nope, quiero guardar el archivo tiro.exe (así lo llamé) cómo  .csv pero me dice que no existe el archivo
Compilarlo y ejecutarlo si me permite

Comment: sera que queres guardar la salida de la ejecucion en un archivo?

Comment: creo que si, lo que quiero guardar son los datos que me arroja el programa después de ejecutarlo(no se si sea lo mismo) para que me muestre los datos en una tabla en excel, no se si me expliqué bien, acabo de comprobarlo con un compañero de clase y a el le permite guardar los datos...estoy empezando a pensar de que se trata sobre algo de mi compu y no se que es

Comment: Ah! Claro. Osea, lo que salgan de datos lo quieres guardar en un archivo de nombre, por ejemplo, "salida.csv", No?

Comment: Si es eso, una opción rápida es (en caso de que uses bash), ejecutes algo como `prompt$ ./nombre_de_tu_programa > archivo.csv`. No sé si en powershell puedas hacer lo mismo, pero supongo que si

Comment: deja intento eso para ver que es lo que ocurre
edición: acabo de intentar lo que me comentaste y me dice que no reconoce el termino...si es algún problema de la computadora misma, me recomiendan hacer algo con ella?

Comment: ¿Solo quieres redirigir la salida de tu programa? Sino puedes abrir manualmente el archivo. Por cierto, también tienes ese problema con otros comandos? Por ejemplo `echo Hola > archivo.txt`

Comment: si, tambien tengo problemas con otros comando, justo un compañero me recomendo tratar de guardarlo con ' archivo.txt ' y me manda el mismo mensaje aunque anteriormente si pude guardarlo como ' archivo.txt '

Comment: No lo he probado, pero te servirá esto? `$ ./tu_prorgama  | Out-File mi_archivo.csv`

Comment: tampoco funciona cuando lo intento, ahora me nombra esto
**is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or    
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**


quite espacios para ver si era algun tipo de fallo de escritura o algo, y lo puse con el formato que colocaste y no me lo guarda

revise si tenia un archivo.txt guardado anteriormente y cuando trato guardarlo como lo guarde ateriormente, ya no me permite el guardarlo como texto, es decir que con otros comando tampoco me funciona

Comment: ¿El problema es solo con Visual Studio Code? ¿O también ejecutando una consola aparte? Se me ocurre que pueda ser una cuestión de permisos.

Comment: pues uso Visual Studio Code y luego cuando abro las consolas solas **cmd y powershell** a parte tampoco me permite, me arroja lo mismo... si es un problema de permisos, sabras como ir con eso?

Comment: Podrías poner en tu publicación cómo es que corres tu archivo? No como lo guardas, sino como lo ejecutas satisfactoriamente.

Comment: Claro, como aparece en la tercera imagen es el como hago que el programa corra y si funciona correctamente